# Spring 4 autowiring of generic classes works in test, doesn't work when deployed to server

Tags: java, spring, generics, autowired, spring-4

I have generic classes which autowires dependencies based on their generic type like this:

```
public abstract class GenericRestService<C extends AbstractTenantEntity> extends RestResource<C> {

    protected final Logger log;
    @Autowired(required = false)
    protected GenericResourceService<C> service;
    @Autowired(required = true)
    protected JpaRepository<C, Long> repo;

 // Now use service if one with specified generic type C is found, otherwise use repo
```

In my spring tests everything works: if no `GenericResourceService<C>` with concrete generic type `C` is defned nothing is injected into field `service` and I happily resort to using `repo` which gets autowired.

However when I run my application in real environment there is always injected some implementation of `GenericResourceService<C>` regardless of whether it's generic type matches type required by dependency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was caused by JDK proxy vs. cglib proxy clash. One was used in deploymen't the other in test.

Answer (score -1):

You might getting multiple bean definition found. Maybe spring 4 does not support dynamic type generics autowiring.